# How to send message from PAM to Display Manager SDDM?

Tags: authentication, debian, pam, display-manager

I'm trying to send a message from the PAM module to the SDDM Display Manager and ultimately reflect the message onto the login screen. I see that [here](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/pull/1486/files) there is a message daemon that the display manager receives but I can't figure out how to send the message from the PAM module itself, specifically in sm_authenticate. Any help would be appreciated!